# Can I pass java window handle to OpenGL-es

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I want to develope with Java + OpenGL(c version).

1. Using java to design the UI.
2. Use OpenGL-es(c version) to render image on the UI.

I know if i want to develope with `Java + C` ,I need JNI .  Beacuse I must create the opengl context first. And this context must be related to a window handle. Can I pass the window's handle which is created by java to the OpenGL API by JNI. Or use `jogl` to intial the opengl envriroment.

Comment: No - Java doesn't provide the information your looking for ...however, you might be able to use something like JNI/JNA to try and find the handle, it depends on how much work yu really want to go to, or you could look at one the open source bindings for OpenGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI, which is the only way to run native code in java, can be used to load a specially generated shared library (.dll in windows, .so on linux/android) and call a native function declared in that library. If you want to write your backend in c, you will have to make a shared library in c with some function for starting your code up, say:

```
void init(void)
{
 ...
}
```

and then another function that looks something like this:

```
void setWindowHandle(void* handle)
{
 ...
}
```

you could then call the first function to start your c code from java, and pass the handle to your c code from java using your the second function.

Besides JNI, which requires the import of certain automatically generated header files, and requires you to go back and forth between java types, i strongly recommend the use of [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) for linking to this shared library. JNA is a wrapper API around JNI which handles type conversion and does not require you to include any java environment code in your c.

On a final note, for simplicity and compatibility of your code, i would recommend writing the opengl interface code in java, using [JOGL](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/)(an opengl binding for standard java), or the java opengl binding provided as part of the android api if this code is for an android device. You may think that the c is a lot faster and should be used, but as far as interfacing with opengl goes, the only really computationally intense code is done by the graphics card, and all the opengl interface code has to do is tell it what to draw.